# code prints white spaces inside a string

Tags: c

i have the next code, in which i have a string "hello world" and it has to convert each character into its ASCII value, but instead of printing [68656C.....] it prints some white spaces right after the '[', like this [......68656C]. And i can´t find the reason why

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,lon;
    char *cod_maq,*c = {"hello world"},c[2];
    lon = strlen(c);
    cod_maq = (char*)malloc((lon+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(i = 0;i < lon;i++)
    {
        sprintf(c,"%X",c[i]);
        strcat(cod_maq,c);
    }
    printf("[%s]\n",cod_maq);
    return 0;
}
```

thanks

Comment: strcat does it. set cod_maq[0] to 0 after alloc

Comment: Please post compilable code.  No C compiler will accept `char *cod_maq,*c = {"hello world"},c[2];` because there are two definitions of `c` in a single line of code.

Comment: The ASCII hex value of `'h'` is `"68"`, how do you propose fitting this string in a two-element `char` array?

Answer (score 2):

The memory in your malloc already contains data that you need to reset.
malloc allocates memory it doesn't initialize it, so you just get random garbage that was there previously.

```
memset(cod_maq, 0, size_of_cod_maq)
```

Comment: might just as well, but all of it doesn't have to be zeroed, just first byte

Comment: `calloc` can be a better option than `malloc`/`memset`.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf(c,"%X",c[i]);` : very bad.

fix to like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int i,lon;
    char *cod_maq, *c = {"hello world"};
    lon = strlen(c);
    cod_maq = (char*)malloc((lon*2 + 1) * sizeof(char));//2 required per character
    for(i = 0; i < lon; i++){
        sprintf(cod_maq + i*2, "%02X", c[i]);
    }
    printf("[%s]\n", cod_maq);
    free(cod_maq);
    return 0;
}
```